# Ansible on Linux server can't ping Windows server

Tags: ansible, kerberos, winrm

I'm trying to ping a Windows server from a Linux server on which I have Ansible installed:

```
ansible windows -i etc/ansible/hosts -m win_ping -u user@REALM.NET -vvvv
```

I get this error:

```
<server.com> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER:  on PORT 5985 TO server.com
<server.com> WINRM CONNECT: transport=kerberos endpoint=http://server.com:5985/wsman
 ...
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 167, in __init__
     kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, '')
 GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), 
    ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))
```

etc/ansible/hosts

```
[windows]
server.com:5985
```

etc/ansible/group_vars/windows.yml

```
 ansible_user: user@REALM.NET
 ansible_pass: password
 ansible_port: 5985
 ansible_connection: winrm
```

etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
         dns_lookup_kdc = true
         dns_lookup_realms = false
         default_realm = REALM.NET
 [realms]
         REALM.NET = {
                 kdc = server.com
         }
 [domain_realm]
         .server.com = REALM.NET
```

I also updated `transport.py` as mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780048/ansible-to-windows-using-kerberos-not-working/30245164#30245164)

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: did you do kinit on your domain user? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#testing-a-kerberos-connection

Comment: @liviu-costea 
Yep, I ran kinit user@REALM.NET. When I run klist: 
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user@REALM.NET

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
10/11/15 20:40:36  10/12/15 06:40:52  krbtgt/REALM.NET@REALM.NET
        renew until 10/12/15 20:40:36

Comment: I had another problem when trying to do something like this (ansible 1.9.2), the group_vars/windows.yml still work on the old version with 'ssh' in the middle, so something like: ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_pass, ansible_ssh_port, ansible_ssh_connection

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't know if this helps, but from this SO post [Ansible windows fails with "Server not found in Kerberos database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184037/ansible-windows-fails-with-server-not-found-in-kerberos-database) it looks like you need to make sure the Linux machine is joined to the domain in order to use Kerberos.  Here is a link explaining how to [join a Linux box to Active Directory domian](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-join-ubuntu-machine-windows-domain)