# Ansible windows fails with "Server not found in Kerberos database"

Tags: ansible, winrm

I am testing ansible (developer build) to connect to  a [windows machine.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#windows-support)

```
ansible 2.0.0 (devel d1b98ec776)
```

The following command fails

```
ansible inh-jnambood-dt.india.mentorg.com -m win_ping -vvvv
```

Error is as below

```
bash-4.1$ ansible inh-jnambood-dt.india.mentorg.com -m win_ping -vvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<inh-jnambood-dt.india.mentorg.com> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: jnambood@MGC.MENTORG.COM on PORT 5985 TO inh-jnambood-dt.india.mentorg.com
inh-jnambood-dt.india.mentorg.com | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "ERROR! kerberos: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377)), plaintext: 401 Unauthorized."
```

`jnambood` is my user id `MGC.MENTORG.COM` is the domain

Clearly there is some step I missed. What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

That usually means that the Linux host where you're running `kinit` is not joined to the domain (ie, it doesn't have a properly configured computer account in the domain). The existing docs unhelpfully omit that requirement...

Comment: Okay. How can I check if that linuxhost is part of domain?   I could run `kinit` and get tickets on that machine

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen this occur where the FQDN of the the host is not entered in both the command and the ansible hosts file.

Try something like:
inh-jnambood-dt.mcg.mentorg.com

HTH

Comment: Had to put "ansible_host=myhost@my.domain.com" in the line of the windows host in the inventory and it worked. Thanks @gm0neyl0ve. There was no need for the linux management machine to "join" the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Ansible, but pywinrm directly. To get things working from a RHEL7 computer to a Windows 10 host in the domain, I changed @ to / in the pywinrm code. I did this because I saw other software use HTTP/hostname and not HTTP@hostname when talking to Kerberos. Hope this is useful for somebody.

https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/pull/141/commits

Answer (score 1):

We had this same error.  For us, it was resolved by shortening the hostname to have less than 15 characters.